# iis 8.5 not caching (azure cloud service)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, cache-control, iis-8.5

I am essentially having the same issue as this person here:
[IIS 8.5 MVC5 Client Cache is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288192/iis-8-5-mvc5-client-cache-is-ignored)

I assume its more an IIS 8.5 config issue rather than anything to do with Azure.
Any thoughts or suggestions??I also tried setting the cache in c# but that didnt work and also tried to add a custom header through the web.config of type 'cache control' but ended up with a mixed result of:

```js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache,max-age=259200
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 11:39:42 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ai_session=24c1f2adcaf647e4b2c3a741d6474618|2015-03-18T11:02:37.3489398+00:00|2015-03-18T11:39:43.2134436+00:00; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2015 12:09:43 GMT; path=/
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Content-Length: 4956
```